# replacing UI elements depending on user selection

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to create a UI that will update depending on what a user selects.  My initial thought was to delete the UI element if it existed and replace it with a new one with new elements. I've looked around for an answer to this, and if there is one out there, I am too new to understand it. 
I have a frame layout that contains a text scroll list.  When something is selected in that list, a function is called to create the part of the UI that fills with controls.  I get the error "NameError: name 'columnLayout' is not defined".
here is the part of the code that I have problems with:

```
if columnLayout(button_layout,exists = True):
    cmds.deleteUI(button_layout)
button_layout = 'button_layout'
ui_elements['column'] = cmds.columnLayout(button_layout)
ui_elements['buttons1']= cmds.button()
ui_elements['buttons2']=cmds.button()
ui_elements['buttons3']=cmds.button()

cmds.formLayout( ui_elements['form_layout'], edit=True, attachForm=[(ui_elements['column'], 'top', 5), (ui_elements['column'], 'right', 20) ] )

cmds.showWindow( window )
```

ui_elements['form_layout'] is created in the previous function.  I appreciate any help, than you very much

Answer (score 0):

You've left off `cmds` in front of `columnLayout` in the first line

Comment: oh wow thats kind of redic of me.  However, even after adding that back in (it is there in my original code) i still get a runtime error: 
RuntimeError: Object 'window12|formLayout133|textScrollList33' not found.

Comment: At least in the code provided you're not creating the text scroll list.  If you deleted the window in between runs you may have a dangling reference to a formLayout that's not there anymore